# Bash command to extract characters in a string

Tags: bash, nginx, sed, awk

I want to write a small script to generate the location of a file in an NGINX cache directory.
The format of the path is:

`/path/to/nginx/cache/d8/40/32/13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032`

Note the last 6 characters: `d8 40 32`, are represented in the path.

As an input I give the md5 hash (`13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032`) and I want to generate the output: `d8/40/32/13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032`

I'm sure sed or awk will be handy, but I don't know yet how...

Answer (score 1):

This awk can make it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""; OFS="/"}{print $(NF-5)$(NF-4), $(NF-3)$(NF-2), $(NF-1)$NF, $0}'
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=""; OFS="/"}`. `FS=""` sets the input field separator to be `""`, so that every char will be a different field. `OFS="/"` sets the output field separator as `/`, for `print` matters.
- `print ... $(NF-1)$NF, $0` prints the penultimate field and the last one all together; then, the whole string. The comma is "filled" with the `OFS`, which is `/`.

#### Test

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=""; OFS="/"}{print $(NF-5)$(NF-4), $(NF-3)$(NF-2), $(NF-1)$NF, $0}' <<< "13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032"
d8/40/32/13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032
```

Or with a file:

```
$ cat a
13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032
13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15f1f2f3

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=""; OFS="/"}{print $(NF-5)$(NF-4), $(NF-3)$(NF-2), $(NF-1)$NF, $0}' a
d8/40/32/13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032
f1/f2/f3/13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15f1f2f3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
echo '13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032' | \
  sed -n 's/\(.*\([0-9a-f]\{2\}\)\([0-9a-f]\{2\}\)\([0-9a-f]\{2\}\)\)$/\2\/\3\/\4\/\1/p;'
```

Having `GNU sed` you can even simplify the pattern using the `-r` option. Now you won't need to escape `{}` and `()` any more. Using `~` as the regex delimiter allows to use the path separator `/` without need to escape it:

```
sed -nr 's~(.*([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2}))$~\2/\3/\4/\1~p;'
```

Output:

```
d8/40/32/13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032
```

---

Explained simple the pattern does the following: It matches:

```
(all (n-5 - n-4) (n-3 - n-2) (n-1 - n-0))
```

and replaces it by

```
/$1/$2/$3/$0
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to separate each of the last 3 bytes from the rest of the hash.

```
hash=13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032
[[ $hash =~ (..)(..)(..)$ ]]
new_path="/path/to/nginx/cache/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}/$hash"
```

Comment: This looks very elegant. Can you explain a bit on `[[ $hash =~ (..)(..)(..)$ ]]`? Does it mean "ends with"?

Comment: Correct. It's a fairly standard regular expression, with 3 capture groups consisting of any two characters each (we could replace `.` with `[0-9a-f]` or something more specific, but this is simpler), followed by an end-of-string. Therefore, it matches the last 3 groups of two. `BASH_REMATCH` is an array whose 0th element contains the entire string matched by the regular expression, and the rest of the elements contain the capture groups from the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
Base="/path/to/nginx/cache/"
echo '13febd65d65112badd0aa90a15d84032' | \
 sed "s|\(.*\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\)|${Base}\2/\3/\4/\1|"

# or
# sed sed 's|.*\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)$|${Base}\1/\2/\3/&|'
```

Assuming info is a correct MD5 (and only) string

Answer (score 0):

First of all - thanks to all of the responders - this was extremely quick!
I also did my own scripting meantime, and came up with this solution:

Run this script with a parameter of the URL you're looking for (`www.example.com/article/76232?q=hello` for example)

```
#!/bin/bash 
path=$1
md5=$(echo -n "$path" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' ')
p3=$(echo "${md5:0-2:2}")
p2=$(echo "${md5:0-4:2}")
p1=$(echo "${md5:0-6:2}")
echo "/path/to/nginx/cache/$p1/$p2/$p3/$md5"
```

This assumes the NGINX cache has a key structure of `2:2:2`.